# can't install ms sql server 2014 express. Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed

Tags: sql-server

I can't install ms sql server 2014 express. At the and get this. Please help me to fix a problem.
[image]

**Error details: § Error installing SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes. Error code: 0x851A001A**

Comment: Have you considered scrolling down the details box to actually see the error details?

Comment: Error details:
§ Error installing SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
Error code: 0x851A001A

Comment: Well have you searched for similar issues, like [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86358/installing-sql-server-2012-wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed) one

Comment: I've followed this link and it helped. [http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86358/installing-sql-server-2012-wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86358/installing-sql-server-2012-wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. In the Services.msc console, change the account of the "SQL Server" service to Local System account (in the service properties). Take note of the account name before changing it, you need it at step #3.
2. Start the service. It should be able to start at this point.
3. Using the SQL Configuration Manager (you won't be able to do it using Services.msc), change the account back to NT Service\MSSQL$